# Go timeouts with concurrent methods

Tags: api, go, concurrency, timeout

I am building a go application that is using some external apis to get data. Unfortunately one of my sources is pretty unreliable, so I would like to implement a timeout function for my api calls, so that my app doesn't get stucked. Unfortunately I don't know how to get started. Could you please help me? Thanks!

```
go func() {
        for {

            ch := make(chan bool, 1)
            defer close(ch)

            apiCall1()

            apiCall2()

            apiCall3()
        }
    }()
```

Comment: What is it that you want to be able to time out? Each of those individual calls?

Comment: https://gobyexample.com/timeouts

Comment: Yes, I would like to time out each call

Answer (score 2):

If your API calls are http requests, the best way to implement a timeout would be specifying one in the http client itself. That way, the `http.Get(url)` will timeout and return an error which can be acted on appropriately. The default http client has an extremely long timeout that can cause applications to hang. Read [this](https://medium.com/@nate510/don-t-use-go-s-default-http-client-4804cb19f779) for a good writeup of this.

Here is a sample implementation of `apiCall1()` that returns an error if one occurs, including a timeout if a response isn't received within 10 seconds.

```
func apiCall1() error {
    var netClient = &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 10,
    }

    resp, err := netClient.Get("http://someurl.com/apiEndpoint")

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return fmt.Errorf("http request returned code %d", resp.StatusCode)
    }

    return handleResponse(resp) // Return error if there is one, nil if not.
}

func handleResponse(resp *http.Response) error {
    ...
}
```

When you call `apiCall1()` you can then handle the error however you want.

```
if err := apiCall1(); err != nil {
    log.Print(err)
}
```

The concurrency aspect of the question is a bit unclear, but i'll leave two bullet points with some ideas:

- `go apiCall1()` and handle errors/timeouts in the `apiCall1()` function.
- https://play.golang.org/p/klee4hwulN This is not perfect, but illustrates how you could use a `WaitGroup` to make the calls concurrent.

Comment: This is the most straightforward solution. This would be my recommendation unless there is some specific reason for the added complexity of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something called as circuit breaker design, if you want to be full proof and robust refer: 
- https://godoc.org/github.com/rubyist/circuitbreaker
- https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html

OR

create something like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func apiCall(u string, checked chan<- bool) {
    time.Sleep(4 * time.Second)
    checked <- true
}


func call(urls []string) bool {

    ch := make(chan bool, 1)
    for _, url := range urls {
        go func(u string) {
            checked := make(chan bool)
            go apiCall(u, checked)
            select {
            case ret := <-checked:
                ch <- ret
            case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
                ch <- false
            }
        }(url)
    }
    return <-ch
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(call([]string{"url1"}))
}
```

Comment: This would be more idiomatic implemented using [`Context.WithTimeout`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithTimeout).

Answer (score 1):

Study `anyCall()` function all the magic is in it :)
Here I'm assuming you want reply from either of 1 of 3 calls or timeout.

https://play.golang.org/p/b-XREKSnP1

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

var sluggishness = 10

// your 3 synchronous unreliable api sources
// time.Sleep() is hard work of your api backends :)
func apiCall1() string {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(rand.Intn(sluggishness)))
    return "api call 1"
}

func apiCall2() string {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(rand.Intn(sluggishness)))
    return "api call 2"
}

func apiCall3() string {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(rand.Intn(sluggishness)))
    return "api call 3"
}

// apiCall makes 3 calls concurrently and returns first
func anyCall() string {
    // our communicaton channels
    api1ret := make(chan string)
    api2ret := make(chan string)
    api3ret := make(chan string)

    // here we fire off 3 api calls concurrently
    go func() {
        // call and block till we get reply
        api1ret <- apiCall1()
        // close channel after we are done
        // since we are only sending one value
        defer close(api1ret)
    }()
    go func() {
        api2ret <- apiCall2()
        defer close(api2ret)
    }()
    go func() {
        api3ret <- apiCall3()
        defer close(api3ret)
    }()

    // select blocks till one of channels unblocks with a value
    // or time.After() unblocks after 5 sec
    select {
    case val := <-api1ret:
        return val

    case val := <-api2ret:
        return val

    case val := <-api3ret:
        return val

    case <-time.After(time.Second * 5):
        return "timeout after 5 sec"
    }
}

func main() {
    // make the apiCall 10 times
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(anyCall())
    }

    fmt.Println("done")
}
```

This is simplistic example that assumes that apiCall1/2/3 always eventually return in the reasonable amount of time. You may want a little more complicated scheme for situations where these calls can block for a very long time. Since all the `go func()` calls will eventually accumulate to a massive leak.

Have fun!

Comment: This would be more idiomatic implemented using [`Context.WithTimeout`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithTimeout).